# MySQL: How to combine partitions of ranges into largest possible contiguous ranges

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to pull off a fairly complex SQL query (maybe simple?) to compress a table with repetitive information. I'm using MySQL 5.7.14 in SequelPro. I'm a novice SQL user with a basic understanding of joins, unions etc. I'm thinking a subquery with some group bys is needed for this one, but I don't know how to do it best.
A simple example of what I'm trying to do is illustrated by the table below:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZoDh.png)

For every col_1 repeated entry, I want to compress into a single entry when the range set by col_2 and 3 (start and end of a range, respectively) overlap. For col_4 and 5, the max value among entries falling in this range should be reported. With the example above, in col_1, there are three ranges for a that overlap and I want to compress this to the min for col_1 and max for col_2 with the max for col_4 and 5. For 'b' in col_2, there are two ranges (31-50, 12-15) that do not overlap, so it would return both rows as is. For c, it would return one row with range 100-300 and values 3, 2 for col_4 and col_5, respectively. The full result desired from this example is shown below:

[query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bHTB.png)

I should add that there are 'null' values in some places that should be treated as zeros.
Does anybody have anybody know the best, and simplest way to do this?
Thank you in advance!!

Update: I've tried using the range setting query suggested but I get an error. The query is as follows:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT range 
  , lower(col_2) AS startdate
  , max(upper(col_3)) OVER (ORDER BY range) AS `end`
   FROM   `combine`
   )
, b AS (
   SELECT *, lag(`end`) OVER (ORDER BY range) < `start` OR NULL AS step
   FROM   a
   )
, c AS (
   SELECT *, count(step) OVER (ORDER BY range) AS grp
   FROM   b
   )
SELECT daterange(min(`start`), max(`end`)) AS range
FROM   c
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The error I receive is:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a AS (SELECT range 
      , lower(col_2) AS startdate
      , max(upper(col_3)) OVE' at line 1**

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do in 1 query.  You can do with cursor (very not efficient), or why you don't do this logic in the code (in your application)?

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial, but it can be done in one single query.

The hard part is combining a set of intervals into the largest possible contiguous intervals. Solutions are detailed in [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100965/combining-separate-ranges-into-largest-possible-contiguous-ranges).

To get the result you are after, you now need to:

1. Calculate the largest possible contiguous intervals for each value in col1, using the query given in the link.

The result, based on your example values, would be:

```
col_1 lower_bound upper_bound
a     20          60
b     12          15
b     31          50
c     100         300
```

2. Associate one of those large intervals to each row in `your_table`. There can only be one such interval per row, so let's `INNER JOIN`:

   `SELECT my_table.*, large_intervals.lower_bound, large_intervals.upper_bound
   FROM my_table
   INNER JOIN (my_awesome_query(your_table)) large_intervals
       ON large_intervals.col1 = my_table.col1
       AND large_intervals.lower_bound <= my_table.col2
       AND large_intervals.upper_bound >= my_table.col3`

You would get:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 lower_bound upper_bound
a    45   50   1    0    20          60
a    50   61   6    0    20          60
a    20   45   0    5    20          60
b    31   50   0    1    31          50
b    12   15   5    0    12          15
c    100  200  3    2    100         300
c    150  300  1    2    100         300
```

3. Then it's easy, just group by col1, lower_bound, upper bound:

`SELECT col1, lower_bound AS col2, upper_bound AS col3, MAX(col4) AS col4, MAX(col5) AS col5 FROM (query above) decorated_table GROUP BY col1, lower_bound, upper_bound`

And you get exactly the result you're after.

**To get back on the hard part**: The post mentioned above exposes solutions for PostgreSQL. MySQL doesn't have range types, but the solution can be adapted. For instance, instead of `lower(range)`, use the lower bound directly `col2`. The solution also makes use of window functions, namely `lag` and `lead`, but that is supported by MySQL, [with the same syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html), so no problem here. Also note that they use `COALESCE(upper(range), 'infinity')` to guard against unbound ranges. Since your ranges are finite, you don't need to care about this, you can simply use the upper range directly, i.e. `col3`. Here's the adaptation:

```
WITH a AS (
   SELECT
       col2,
       col3,
       col2 AS lower_bound, 
       MAX(col3) OVER (ORDER BY col2, col3) AS upper_bound
   FROM   combine
   )
, b AS (
   SELECT *, lag(upper_bound) OVER (ORDER BY col2, col3) < lower_bound OR NULL AS step
   FROM   a
   )
, c AS (
   SELECT *, count(step) OVER (ORDER BY col2, col3) AS grp
   FROM   b
   )
SELECT
    MIN(lower_bound) AS lower_bound,
    MAX(upper_bound) AS range
FROM   c
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This works for a single group. If you want to get the ranges by col1, you can tweak it like this:

```
WITH a AS (
   SELECT
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col2 AS lower_bound, 
       MAX(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2, col3) AS upper_bound
   FROM   combine
   )
, b AS (
   SELECT *, lag(upper_bound) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2, col3) < lower_bound OR NULL AS step
   FROM   a
   )
, c AS (
   SELECT *, count(step) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2, col3) AS grp
   FROM   b
   )
SELECT
    MIN(lower_bound) AS lower_bound,
    MAX(upper_bound) AS range
FROM   c
GROUP  BY col1, grp
ORDER  BY 1;
```

**Combining everything**, we get the following, which (tested on the example you provided), returns exactly the output you expected:

```
WITH a AS (
   SELECT
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col2 AS lower_bound, 
       MAX(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2, col3) AS upper_bound
   FROM   combine
   )
, b AS (
   SELECT *, lag(upper_bound) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2, col3) < lower_bound OR NULL AS step
   FROM   a
   )
, c AS (
   SELECT *, count(step) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2, col3) AS grp
   FROM   b
   )
, large_intervals AS (
    SELECT
        col1,
        MIN(lower_bound) AS lower_bound,
        MAX(upper_bound) AS upper_bound
    FROM   c
    GROUP  BY col1, grp
    ORDER  BY 1
    )
, combine_with_large_interval AS (
    SELECT
        combine.*,
        large_intervals.lower_bound,
        large_intervals.upper_bound
    FROM combine
    INNER JOIN large_intervals
        ON large_intervals.col1 = combine.col1
        AND large_intervals.lower_bound <= combine.col2
        AND large_intervals.upper_bound >= combine.col3
)
SELECT
    col1,
    lower_bound AS col2,
    upper_bound AS col3, 
    MAX(col4) AS col4, 
    MAX(col5) AS col5
FROM combine_with_large_interval
GROUP BY col1, lower_bound, upper_bound
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3;
```

Voilà !

Comment: Thank you for your response Mattieu!

Comment: Thank you Mattieu! You're clear that I need to combine a set of intervals (define a range) for each col_1 value, then inner join to link it to the original table. However, I'm not sure how to execute the first step described in the link. It gives four different approaches to do this- which should I use? I think my example is much different from the one in the former post because I'm using info from two columns to build this range. The sql functions used are beyond my knowledge, make me question whether I should use SQL or something else instead.  I appreciate if you can make this more clear!

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer how to adapt the solution to your use case, I think you're good to go now. You're fine with MySQL, even though Postgres is more flexible. You don't really need to understand the intricacies of the solutions mentioned in the post, just replace the names with yours, and check that the output satisfies you :) Maybe apply the algorithm on a sheet of paper to get a feeeling of how this works and why.

Comment: Thanks, I understand and adapted my input for the 'get ranges' query, but I'm getting errors I don't recognize. They are in the 'update' portion of my post above, along with the query I used. I appreciate if you have any advice

Comment: You've got the solution in full now ;)

Comment: Tested on Postgres and everything works fine, it should be the same on MySQL. To convert NULL values into 0s, use `COALESCE(..., 0)` everywhere you need to.

Comment: I would also recommend editing the title to something more meaningful, like "How to combine partitions of ranges into largest possible contiguous ranges"

Comment: Thanks for adapting it. Unfortunately, it looks like MySQL does not support Window Functions. As a result, the Over clause cannot be used. I wonder if there is a way around this? Otherwise, I will try to move it to Postgres :-)

Comment: Which version are you using? 8.0 supports window functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html